# how to group a data in a column

Tags: analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics

I am having a dataset with device OS versions in a column (say Android 5.1, Android 4.3.2, iPhone, iPod, iPad, etc).

Is there a way to group them saying Android (all Android 5.1, and Android 4.3.2 are considered) and iOS (saying all iPhone, iPod and iPad are considered)?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another column to the dataset as suggested or you can use custom code to do the grouping. The code approach will limit your ability to drill-down or filter by clicking directly on the lens.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to add another column with 2 categories iDevice / Android, and associate them in the data.